# Modifying SXA checklist Filter facet

Tags: sxa, content-search

I have added the checklist filter from the SXA search component. I have to modify the dropdown by entering the box and autocompleting. I would like to modify like the below one

[image: This is my existing function]

**without typing a word**
[image: without typing a word]

**with typing a word** - [image: With typing a word]

Comment: I think it's require custom component implementation. You can try looking into implementation of existing filter component and use JavaScript frameworks https://bashooka.com/coding/autocomplete-autosuggest-javascript-libraries/

Comment: Thank you @AmitKumar. Let me check